# How Does the Community User Set Bounties?

Tags: support, bounties, community-user

I decided on poking around some profiles and I hit the [Community user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community). I knew that Community was a background process but then I noticed that it had set some bounties. What criteria does Community follow to know what questions to set bounties on? Are these questions with a lot of views or upvotes or all of the above?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Community doesn't add bounties. Both of the bounties that are currently attributed to Community were actually added by a user who has since been deleted. When the user was deleted the bounty was transfered to Community's ownership.

If you look at [one of the the bountied question's revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/10154118/revisions), there's a discrepancy that points to this:

> [image]

Normally, the *Notice Added* event is attributed to the same person as the *Bounty Started* event. It looks like the ownership of the *Notice Added* event was not transfered, so it is no longer attributed to anybody. The cause is probably related to *Notice Added* events being a somewhat unique type of event that was added relatively recently, while bounties just are considered a type of vote.

Comment: And I here I was, thinking about how I could get Community to post up a bounty on my question. :)

Comment: @Yawus There have been some feature requests related to having Community add bounties automatically ([one example](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108620/community-bounties-request-for-comments)), but I'm afraid that none have been implemented yet. :P

Comment: @Yawus you can, just post a bounty and be deleted!

Comment: Mini-question: Can Community Wiki have more than 3 bounties at once?

Answer (score 21):

Just as a side note: While the Community User's profile calls him a background process, that's really just a simple explanation in the easiest possible terms.

All it technically is is a special user account that's used in places where we need a user id, but no user is actually responsible for whatever the thing in question is, maybe (as in this case) because a user doesn't exist anymore, or we need a pseuo-edit (a.k.a. bump), or the actual action was anonymous (as can happen for suggested edits). There's no "AI process" surfing on Stack Overflow. [Just an id](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/who-is-the-community-user#comment351111_19739) to fulfill a foreign key constraint, if you will.

He/she/it *does* [get yelled at](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129090/115866) sometimes, though. But we still love him/her/it.

Comment: Not everybody loves [that credit stealing bot](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116339/community-user-dismissing-close-flags-as-helpful-stealing-credit-from-mods) ;-) That aside, it also [has its favorites](http://stackexchange.com/users/-1/community?tab=favorites)...?

Comment: Does the community user also put bounties on things with enough "this was helpful" feedback or something? Although they don't show up on its profile page, I've seen +25 bounties from Community, which aren't possible to give normally, so...?

Comment: @minitech The community user *doesn't put bounties at all*. See the accepted answer.

Comment: I figured something might have changed. So there are no +25 bounties anywhere? (I have a screenshot somewhere to prove it! With tooltip!)

Comment: Never mind, just being stupid... it was a 50 awarded automatically.

Comment: @minitech Here is +25 bounty by community: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20851629/how-to-configure-jms-in-jboss-6/20923328#20923328