# Is the community bot remotely controlled?

Tags: support, community-user

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Who is the Community user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/who-is-the-community-user)

On the [community bots user profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community), it says:

> Hi, I'm not really a person.
>
> I'm a background process that helps keep this site clean!

I just saw that the Community bot edited an answer. But this edit does not look like it has been done by a bot.

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/767213/revisions

What happened there? Is the bot remotely controlled?

Comment: +1 agree with you, if it wasn't human, it would do only static actions.

Comment: The particular case you saw is what happens when an anonymous user has suggested an edit. Since there's no actual Stack Overflow user who suggested the edited, and *someone* has to take credit for it, the community user is used for this. Also see [this answer of mine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/139538/115866).

Comment: "Remotely controlled"? You mean, like from the orbital platform?

Comment: Sorry, I am not a native speaker. Actually *(to) remote control* is the right verb for the kind of stuff you are doing with a *remote control*, am I right?

Comment: But actually I like the idea of the stackoverflow staff circling around in low earth orbit, programming bots from above. So I won't change the title. :)

Comment: It's just the NULL user in the database, to be more precise.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Is the bot remotely controlled?

Nope, it's not a bot but rather a user that takes all the stick.

What do I mean? Well, if for example a post is deleted by flagging from multiple users, it shows up as deleted by community. If a post is edited by an anonymous user, it belongs to community and so on and so forth.

Basically, where a user might ordinarily have been attributed, if no one user can be, or no user can be, community shows up as responsible.

The user does also take some actions on a periodic basis such as editing posts just to bump them, and so on.

Comment: That means it is not an auto controlled system, its manual. am i correct ?

Comment: @Lucifer no. There's nobody sat there controlling the community user - it's the user that gets assigned to tasks no user can be attributed to. Nobody uses it, it just happens to own some human generated content.

Comment: ok got it. it has been programmed such a way.

Answer (score 4):

[That](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/164728) is a suggested edit done from an anonymous user. The "suggested" link takes you to the page showing you the suggested edit.

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

When it comes to suggested edits, and approving them, what is reported as something done by the Community user is really done from a human being. The Community user is not really able to suggest edits, nor is there anybody that logs in using the Community user account.