# How did Community ♦ post a bounty on a question?

Tags: support, bounties, community-user

I am baffled by the following question bounty banner:

[image: Community bounty?!]

When is a bounty attributed to Community ♦?

Comment: Duplicate of https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139533/369802 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [timeline](https://law.stackexchange.com/posts/51759/timeline) of the question is pretty clear about it:

[image]

The notice is attributed to the deleted user (you're a moderator, so you should be able to see something about the deleted account) but the bounty has been 'hijacked' by the Community user.