# Stop bumping questions that nobody cares about

Tags: feature-request, community-user, bump

This is a follow-up of [What is the point to show to anonymous users posts bumped by Community user? How to prevent that bad questions be bumped in low participation sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/388634/289691)

Bumps by Community-User are intended to increase the number of views of neglected posts, which is fine, but it doesn't make sense that questions that nobody cares about be bumped indefinitely.

Please stop bumping a question when all of the following conditions are true:

The question

- is +3 years old,
- has low votes, upvotes + downvotes < 5 OR the question score is lower or equal to -5,
- has 0 answers OR the most recent answer is +3 years old,
- the OP has not visited the site in +1 year OR the OP's account is deleted OR OP is suspended for more than 1 year (suspension applied by a CM).

---

## Top 30 Sites

Number of bumped questions by site ([source](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1745097/number-of-bumped-questions-by-site))

| site | >40 | > 20 <= 40 | >10 <= 20 | <=10 | Count | Total # of bumps |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| StackOverflow | 923 | 1601 | 5019 | 7381 | 14924 | 206180 |
| SuperUser | 449 | 745 | 3141 | 3414 | 7749 | 107492 |
| ServerFault | 378 | 772 | 2999 | 3472 | 7621 | 101672 |
| StackOverflow.Es | 3 | 270 | 1456 | 2845 | 4574 | 47173 |
| StackExchange.Gis | 0 | 106 | 1201 | 3082 | 4389 | 40656 |
| StackExchange.Ell | 5 | 248 | 1066 | 3040 | 4359 | 42327 |
| StackExchange.Stats | 15 | 224 | 1246 | 2831 | 4316 | 42975 |
| StackExchange.Blender | 24 | 288 | 1196 | 2808 | 4316 | 44517 |
| StackExchange.Physics | 21 | 270 | 1248 | 2729 | 4268 | 44354 |
| StackExchange.Magento | 34 | 449 | 1746 | 2035 | 4264 | 52598 |
| StackExchange.Electronics | 0 | 266 | 1264 | 2684 | 4214 | 42831 |
| StackExchange.Wordpress | 48 | 407 | 1754 | 2005 | 4214 | 51698 |
| StackExchange.Unix | 78 | 373 | 1542 | 2221 | 4214 | 50675 |
| StackExchange.Math | 37 | 369 | 1289 | 2504 | 4199 | 46922 |
| StackOverflow.Ru | 0 | 285 | 1244 | 2665 | 4194 | 43123 |
| StackExchange.Dba | 28 | 347 | 1379 | 2426 | 4180 | 46702 |
| StackOverflow.Pt | 18 | 371 | 1392 | 2363 | 4144 | 46825 |
| StackExchange.Ubuntu | 91 | 439 | 1452 | 2043 | 4025 | 50877 |
| StackExchange.Sharepoint | 137 | 504 | 1794 | 1466 | 3901 | 55441 |
| StackExchange.Ethereum | 0 | 273 | 1257 | 2188 | 3718 | 39187 |
| StackExchange.Drupal | 163 | 476 | 1746 | 1304 | 3689 | 54101 |
| StackExchange.Datascience | 1 | 98 | 987 | 2331 | 3417 | 32308 |
| StackExchange.Android | 41 | 536 | 632 | 1960 | 3169 | 43480 |
| StackExchange.Raspberrypi | 47 | 434 | 1012 | 1656 | 3149 | 40023 |
| StackExchange.Salesforce | 41 | 313 | 931 | 1715 | 3000 | 35313 |
| StackExchange.Apple | 0 | 2 | 591 | 2238 | 2831 | 24387 |
| StackExchange.Diy | 9 | 254 | 641 | 1883 | 2787 | 29479 |
| StackExchange.WebApps | 29 | 164 | 842 | 1670 | 2705 | 28850 |
| StackExchange.GameDev | 30 | 354 | 687 | 1356 | 2427 | 31062 |

## Related

### Meta Stack Exchange

#### Feature Request

- [Would it be feasible to have Community only poke questions of active users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/48410/289691) [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

### Sound Design Meta

- ['Community' keeps bumping old "dead" threads](https://sound.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1346)

### Stack Overflow Meta

- [Should the Community bot stop bumping dead questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/412115/1595451)

### Tor Meta

- [Community bot bumping dead, answered posts](https://tor.meta.stackexchange.com/q/389)

Comment: Note that "has 0 answers" and "question score is lower or equal to [0]" are already conditions that will result in not bumping a post.

Comment: IMHO, a simpler solution would be "don't bump a post more than X times"

Comment: @RyanM I'm pretty sure have seen question with 0 answers and score lower or equal to 0 bumped by Community User ... maybe these conditions occurred after the bump or were bumped for another reason. I will add such cases if you found them again. Regarding the simple solution, how many times do you consider that is enough? How about 10? The complexity of the rules is to keep bumping apparently "good" questions.

Comment: Possibly helpful info - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412115/should-the-community-bot-stop-bumping-dead-questions/412121#412121

Comment: Sometimes a question with a low score may not be a bad question as a whole. Sometimes, all it takes is a good answer to shed light on the importance of the problem and add value, turning a low-interest question into a well-voted one. That's why we have two badges, [Lifejacket](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/313/lifejacket) and [Lifeboat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/314/lifeboat).

Comment: @AugustoVasques This feature request is not saying that questions are good or bad. Questions are competing for attention, questions that are +3 years old plus the other criteria, already had enough changes to get attention from the homepage viewers.

Comment: @Rubén: I inferred quality because the *"questions that nobody cares"* criterion is very vague and two of the classification criteria are *"has low votes, upvotes + downvotes < 5 OR the question score is lower or equal to -5"* and *"has 0 answers OR the most recent answer is +3 years old,"* which are directly related to the medals I mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @AugustoVasques. This feature request doesn't avoid people from finding these questions and answering them. It's not asking to close or delete them. Several of these questions can be found in the unanswered tab among many other ways.

Comment: At no point in your request were the words "delete" or "close" mentioned, and at no point did I refer to them. My problem is that the request tries to establish a selection criteria for which questions will be bumped on the home page based on a subjective criterion that, as I said, does not prevent people from finding these questions, but imposes a barrier of difficulty for them to find the "questions that nobody cares about". I'm sorry, but I disagree with the proposal. Perhaps a better alternative would be for the site to reduce the frequency with which posts are bumped by the Community User

Comment: [I also tried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21xyL.png)

Answer (score 14):

I believe the benefits outweigh the issues you raise.

The age, answers, and whether or not the OP is still around have no bearing on the quality of a question, and the amount of votes is a very relative measurement of quality.

Queriers come and go, but so do users with specialized interests and knowledge who might be able to answer an old and forgotten query.

A better change would be to prevent a torrent of Community-bumped questions from flooding a low-activity site, by setting a limit, but that might be difficult to implement.

Comment: Note that the bumping is supposed to be to vote on the answers; it's not looking for people to _answer_ the question; it's looking for people to evaluate _existing_ answers.

Comment: @RyanM Well, both, I think. And if a question has answers that require upvoting to prevent the question from being bumped, the answers might simply not be adequate enough, in which case a better answer is still a preferred solution, right?

Comment: Please propose a "measure of quality". Regarding the limit, currently, there is a setting to limit the number of questions that are bumped by the hour. The default value is 1. This is not working for some sites like Web Applications. I don't think that this also works for some of the sites that I added to the initial question before posting this one (Super User, Computer Science, Magento) having posts that have been bumped +40 times.

Comment: So let each community decide for themselves, as they can for privilege thresholds. "benefits > issues" is something most users in at least one network would strongly disagree with. It's a very simple issue, really - a site with x100 less activity shouldn't have the same bumping. If this is hard to imagine, imagine half of all posts of anyone's StackOverflow being bumps. And they're not new bumps, they're something each user has already seen at least five times. Yes, it's **that bad**.

Answer (score 9):

In your linked post, your main argument about bumping questions in general is this:

> IMO, it is a problem that the landing page for anonymous users shows Community-user bumped posts when most of these questions **aren't good questions.**

Fine. **Then the solution is to downvote the questions**. For a question to have been bumped, it has to have a positive score- or in other words, at least *one* person thought that it was a good question. But if you disagree with the assessment, just downvote it. And if they were genuinely bad, they should have been downvoted in the first place; if they were actually off-topic, they should have been closed.

In this post, you write:

> Bumps by Community-User are intended to increase the number of views of neglected posts, which is fine, but it doesn't make sense that questions that nobody cares about be bumped indefinitely.

Well, they're intended to increase the number of views, but that itself is not the point- the point is to have people vote on the answers. So the other solution is to **upvote the answers if they're useful.**

---

Your suggestions for when not to bump:

> - 1] is +3 years old,
> - 2] has low votes, upvotes + downvotes < 5 OR the question score is lower or equal to -5,
> - 3]  has 0 answers OR the most recent answer is +3 years old,
>   the OP has not visited the site in +1 year OR the OP's account is deleted OR OP is suspended for more than 1 year (suspension applied by a CM).
>   feature

Presumably, you mean to say that if a question meets these requirements, nobody cares about it.

For 1] - Just because a question is old doesn't mean nobody cares about it.

For 2] - Negatively scored questions aren't bumped. Plus, you need to clarify what 'low votes' means. It's also relative to the site: On smaller sites, even a score of 2 is pretty good, but on the biggest sites, this isn't so impressive.

For 3] - A missing OP just means that the answer isn't going to get accepted soon. It doesn't detract from the quality or relevance of the question itself.

(Your other suggestion, having to do with answer-age, is more similar to your first idea.)

---

None of the sites I'm active on *have* too many bumped questions, so I'll admit that I don't know exactly what I'm talking about, nor do I know how annoying it may be. Perhaps there's some sort of a solution somewhere, but it's not a good idea to have cookie-cutter rules that would have different effects on each site.

Answer (score 3):

I like your idea but it's not an idea that can get traction to be done. In reality it's not an "one size fit all" situation. That's why the community's bump change requests never get done.

In reality each site should be able to choose the conditions. For example on the site I moderate the reason you stated are not valid. The vote ratio is low and the age mean nothing, but a valid reason would be a question tagged for a product that is end of life for a long long time (like for Windows Server 2003).